# Программа на C++ вылетает при работе из среды NetBeans при использовании cout

Tags: c++, netbeans

В среде NetBeans, работающей под Ubuntu возникают проблемы при выполнении следующего, например кода

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int num;
    char str[20];
    cout << "Enter number" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << num << endl << "Enter string" << endl;
    cin >> str;
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод выглядит следующим образом. Причём выглядит так не всегда, иногда всё происходит корректно.

```
Enter number
5
5
Enter string
tg

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 3s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть причина подобного поведения?

Comment: "при работе из среды NetBeans" - а если запустить скомпилированный файл не из Netbeans, а просто так?

Comment: Если запускать не из среды, то всё нормально. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: О каком "подобном поведении" идет речь? Что вы увидели необычного в приведенном выводе? О каком "вылете" идет речь?

Answer (score 1):

Так

```
char str[20];
cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
```

так

```
char str[20];
cin.get(str, sizeof(str));
```

или так

```
#include <string>

string str; //or std::string
cin >> str;
```

Comment: Добавил getline. Получил вообще
Enter number
6

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 2s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

Comment: cout << num << endl - эта команда выводит num еще раз. Или в чем у вас проблема?

Comment: У меня просто срывается программа (периодически, не при каждом запуске) при использовании cout. При запуске из консоли обычной (не из среды разработки) всё нормально

Comment: Это зависит от ввода числа и строки? Неверное число или длинная строка...

Comment: Не зависит. С одним и тем же вводом netbeans правильно выполняет программу через раз или реже, в терминале всё хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Так а где вылет??? В приведенном вами выводе никакого вылета не видно. Все отработало нормально. Все выглядит корректно, за исключением "отсутствующего" вывода последней строки. Ну так сделайте

```
cout << str << endl;
```

Буфер-то выходной надо выталкивать на выход, что делается, например, через `endl`. А вытолкнется он или нет сам по себе - зависит от внешних факторов. Поэтому в разных средах по-разному и работает.

Comment: Странно. На [cppreference пишут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl): _In most other usual interactive I/O scenarios, `std::endl` is redundant when used with `std::cout` because any input from `std::cin`, output to `std::cerr`, **or program termination** forces a call to `std::cout.flush()`._

Comment: @VladD: Да, это так. Но я подозреваю, что по какой-то причине именно этого и не происходит из-под NetBeans. По крайней мере никакого "вылета" я пока нигде не вижу.

Comment: То есть, это по сути баг netbeans?